# String is too long and would be truncated

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SRC(SRC_STRING VARCHAR(20))
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TGT(tgt_STRING VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO SRC VALUES('JKNHJYGHTFGRTYGHJ')

INSERT INTO TGT(TGT_STRING) SELECT SRC_STRING::VARCHAR(10) FROM SRC
```

```
Error: String 'JKNHJYGHTFGRTYGHJ' is too long and would be truncated
```

Is there any way we can enable enforce length(not for COPY command)  while inserting data from high precision to low precision column?

Comment: Copying data from high varchar length column  to low varchar length column is not an issue. What are you looking for ?

Comment: updated the description, it's about sql INSERT statement not COPY command.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the SUBSTR( ) function, to pick the piece of data you want, example as follows where I take the first 10 characters (if available, if there were only 5 it'd use those 5 characters).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE SRC(
    src_string VARCHAR(20));

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TGT(
    tgt_STRING VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO src 
VALUES('JKNHJYGHTFGRTYGHJ');

INSERT INTO tgt(tgt_string) 
SELECT SUBSTR(src_string, 1, 10) 
FROM SRC;

SELECT * FROM tgt; --JKNHJYGHTF
```

Here's the documentation on the function:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/substr.html

Comment: I am aware of SUBSTR function, am looking for some option similar to ENFORCE_LENGTH (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#copy-options-copyoptions), but i couldn't find such option in Snowflake doc.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for exactly the same functionality that the ENFORCE_LENGTH option in COPY command has, this isn't natively available, but is fairly easy to construct.

The "false" option for that can be replicated with the above original answer.

The "true" option can be replicated with something like the below command, though it does not FAIL, it simply inserts zero records.

INSERT INTO tgt(tgt_string) 
SELECT src_string
FROM (
  SELECT src_string, 
         MAX(LENGTH(src_string)) OVER () as max_length
  FROM   SRC
)
WHERE max_length <= 10;